# Bind DropDownList to a collection in a collection of Objects

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am attempting to bind a Dropdownlist to properties in a collection that are contained within a List of Objects.

I have an object that has a properties collection in it so if I have an individual instance of the object I can call the property like so:

```
MyObject.Properties["Title"].Value.ToString();
```

Now I have a

```
List<MyObject>
```

and I would like to bind the Properties["Title"].Value.ToString to the DataValueField in a dropdown list.

```
dropDownList.DataSource = List<MyObject>
dropDownList.DataValueField = "Title";
dropDownList.DataBind();
```

Of course this does not work because Title is in the Properties collection and is not a property of the object.

```
dropDownList.DataValueField = "Properties[\"Title\"]"
```

also does not work because Properties["Title"] is also not a property of the object. I have tried a couple of other variations and am not having any luck. Is there a way to do this or do I need to iterate through the objects, make a list\dictionary of the key value pairs and use that. It seems to me there should be a way to do this. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd just use a Linq Select to set up an anonymous object:

```
dropDownList.DataSource = myObjectList
    .Select(item => new { Title = item.Properties["Title"] })
    .ToList();
dropDownList.DataValueField = "Title";
```